# livereload.js causing react site to load slow

Tags: reactjs, livereload

Currently having the most infuriating issue regarding my sites load speed. I thought it was an api loading issue, but it turns out that my production build is causing a livereload.js?snipver=1 issue. It says (pending) for about a minute, and then fails. Is there any way to get rid of livereload or prevent it from coming up in my production build? Is this the issue or is it something else that I'm not seeing? site is [www.acquired.homes](http://www.acquired.homes)

Any help is greatly appreciated, let me know if any of my files would help!

Comment: Seems you did not run a production build

Comment: @ShivamJha I am. I've even manually deployed the build folder on an AWS server as well and same result.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64634192/11667949

Comment: Same here, I moved each dev deps in the "devDependencies" section in package.json, then run "yarn build", but still got this livereload script in production

Comment: @Nemus I ended up solving the issue by just creating a new build from scratch. Not sure if a dependency got messed up or something, but I created a new vanilla CRA build, ran 'npm run build' right away, then just started copying over the files from my original project. Hope this helps you!